# How to hide exact date and just show range in tooltip using google chart

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

In the below I am trying the point's tooltip to show the range instead of the exact time e.g. Instead of '5:30' it should show '5-6pm' in the tooltip.I try put an column role but then it doesn't stay dynamic with the range of the graph

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Load the Visualization API and the corechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart','line']});
      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.
      function drawChart() {
        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('datetime', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number','cat1');
        data.addRows([
          [new Date("2017-08-09T13:00:00.000Z"),145289],
          [new Date("2017-08-09T12:00:00.000Z"),138370],
          [new Date("2017-08-09T11:00:00.000Z"),117605],
          [new Date("2017-08-09T10:00:00.000Z"),81268],
          [new Date("2017-08-09T09:00:00.000Z"),59815],
          [new Date("2017-08-09T08:00:00.000Z"),51899]
        ]);
        //console.log(data);
        var options = {
          'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
           //focusTarget: 'category',
           showCategories:true
        };
        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 50%;height:50%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Google Chart Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYTTX.png)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a [DataView](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView) to add a calculated column for the tooltip role

as for showing the range,
recommend using google's [DateFormat](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dateformat) to get hour and am/pm, for both the begin and end hour
as well as calculating a new date for the end hour

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('datetime', 'Topping');
  data.addColumn('number', 'cat1');
  data.addRows([
    [new Date("2017-08-09T13:00:00.000Z"),145289],
    [new Date("2017-08-09T12:00:00.000Z"),138370],
    [new Date("2017-08-09T11:00:00.000Z"),117605],
    [new Date("2017-08-09T10:00:00.000Z"),81268],
    [new Date("2017-08-09T09:00:00.000Z"),59815],
    [new Date("2017-08-09T08:00:00.000Z"),51899]
  ]);

  var formatHour = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: 'ha'
  });

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, {
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      var oneHour = (1000 * 60 * 60);
      var rowDate = dt.getValue(row, 0);
      var rangeHour1 = formatHour.formatValue(rowDate);
      var rangeHour2 = formatHour.formatValue(new Date(rowDate.getTime() + oneHour));
      return rangeHour1 + '-' + rangeHour2;
    },
    type: 'string',
    role: 'tooltip'
  }]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```